# Dataframe column based on 4 conditions, nested np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The dataframe with which I am working has 4 possible combinations over 2 columns and several hundred groups.

```
| Group |   Before   |    After   |
|:-----:|:----------:|:----------:|
|   G1  |  Injection |  Injection |
|   G1  |  Injection | Production |
|   G1  | Production |  Injection |
|   G1  | Production | Production |
```

There are 3 pre-calculated columns which need to be pulled based on the Before/After combination as seen below.

```
| Group |   Before   |    After   |         Output         |
|:-----:|:----------:|:----------:|:----------------------:|
|   G1  |  Injection |  Injection |        df['DTI']       |
|   G1  |  Injection | Production | df['DTWF'] + df['DTP'] |
|   G1  | Production |  Injection | df['DTWF'] + df['DTI'] |
|   G1  | Production | Production |        df['DTP']       |
```

I have tried nesting multiple np.where's

```
np.where(df['Before'] == 'Injection' & df['After'] == 'Injection', df['DTI'],
np.where(....))
```

Which resulted in:

> ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

and nesting multiple np.logical:

```
np.where(np.logical_and(df['Before'] == 'Injection' & df['After'] == 'Injection'), df['DTP'])
```

Which resulted in:

> the truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have reached the upper limit of what I can do and need some ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using apply function:

Assuming your DataFrame is in variable `df` you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Before": ["Injection", "Injection", "Production", "Production"],
                        "After": ["Injection", "Production", "Injection", "Production"]})
def get_output(x):
    if x['Before'] == 'Injection' and x['After'] == 'Injection':
        return 'DTI'
    elif x['Before'] == 'Injection' and x['After'] == 'Production':
        return 'DTWF + DTP'
    elif x['Before'] == 'Production' and x['After'] == 'Injection':
        return 'DTWF + DTI'
    elif x['Before'] == 'Production' and x['After'] == 'Production':
        return 'DTP'

df['Output'] = df.apply(get_output, axis=1)
```

Comment: I implemented using & instead of 'and' given Panda's requirements:



    `def get_output(x):
        if patt_vols[(df['Before'] == 'Injection') & (df['After'] == 'Injection')]:
            return df['DTI']
        elif patt_vols[(df['Before'] == 'Injection') & (df['After'] == 'Production')]:
            return patt_vols['DTWF'] + patt_vols['DTP']
    ...`


However, I am receiving: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. error

Comment: @Quasar I updated the code to complete the answer. It should work.

Comment: I found my issue. I was calling the original df name and not the parameter. This did exactly as needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Before["Injection"]` does not do what you think it does. In the code you showed it is not even defined.

What you probably want is this:

```
# df definition, skipping Group because it is not needed here
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Before": ["Injection", "Injection", "Production", "Production"], "After": ["Injection", "Production", "Injection", "Production"]})

df["Output"] = "DTI"  # Use one of the cases as default
df.loc[(df["Before"] == "Injection") & (df["After"] == "Production"), "Output"] = "DTWF + DTP"
df[(df["Before"] == "Production") & (df["After"] == "Injection"), "Output"] = "DTWF + DTI"
df[(df["Before"] == "Production") & (df["After"] == "Production"), "Output"] = "DTP"
print(df)
#         After      Before      Output
# 0   Injection   Injection         DTI
# 1  Production   Injection  DTWF + DTP
# 2   Injection  Production  DTWF + DTI
# 3  Production  Production         DTP
```

If you have many of these combinations, using `apply` as suggested in the other answer might be more appropriate.

If you have many rows it might make sense to save the boolean indices (e.g. `df["Before"] == "Production"`) to variables and just do

```
before_prod = df["Before"] == "Production"
after_prod = df["After"] == "Production"
df.loc[before_prod & after_prod, "Output"] = "DTP"
...
```

If you also only have those two states, you can get the second one (almost) for free by using the unary negation operator `~`:

```
df.loc[before_prod & ~after_prod, "Output"] = "DTWF + DTI"
```

Comment: `df.loc[(df["Before"] == "Injection") & (df["After"] == "Production"),'Output'] = ... ` is the widely known pandas way.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat And one I always forget. Is there actually a performance bonus associated with it or is it just that chaining too many indices ends up modifying not the original object but some intermediate object?